# Eureka Server doesn't discover multiple instances of the same client

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have very basic EurekaServer

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.85
eureka.server.renewal-threshold-update-interval-ms=900000
```

Then I setup multiple eureka clients marked as **@EnableDiscoveryClient**. All are set to random **port 0** and have unique application name like this:

```
server.port=0
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
# unique name of the service
spring.application.name=product-service
```

I boot up EurekaServer and all my clients. I also allowed for multiple instances of the same service to run. It looks like this:

[image]

The problem is when I run Eureka server dashboard it shows all services run on **port 0** and it doesn't register multiple instances of InventoryServiceApplication running.

[image]

Even bigger problem is when I drop the first instance of InventoryServiceApplication it will show it as "down", however there are still two instances running. Am I missing some kind of configuration to fix Eureka server ? How can I fix Eureka Server so it will register multiple instances and starts showing correct ports ?

Comment: Yup, it doesn't work with a random port as the port is used in the instance id. Either set the port or the instance id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it does not recognise random port, instead we can run the application instances deliberately on differents ports by "adding VM options".

1. Go to "Edit configuration settings" of the application.
2. Click on "Modify Options" and then select "Add VM Options"
3. Enter the command "-Dserver.port= portnumber" eg - -Dserver.port=9091.
4. Click on run and then refresh eureka server.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it by configuring the instance id for Eureka instance. Here is my configuration file.

```
server.port=0
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=inventory-service
```

Comment: adding different id worked for me.